# Matlab: cannot access method "myMethod" in class "matlabClass"

Tags: matlab, methods

I wrote a function "transform" to which I pass a vector [0*sym(pi),..], but I get the error:  Error using sym/transform
Cannot access method 'transform' in class 'sym'.

How can I fix this?

transform.m

```
function [ t_vec ] = transform( points, angles,length )
t_vec = ones(3,size(angles,2))
for i = 1:size(angles,2)
    iki = ikin(points(1,i),points(2,i),angles(i),length);
    t_vec(1,i) = iki(1)
    t_vec(2,i) = iki(2)
    t_vec(3,i) = iki(3)
end
end
```

ikin.m

```
function [theta,theta2] = ikin(ox,oy,omega,length) 
o_wrist = [ox-length(3)*cos(omega);oy-length(3)*sin(omega);0];
l = sqrt(o_wrist(1)^2+o_wrist(2)^2);
stuff = (l^2-length(1)^2-length(2)^2)/(2*length(1)*length(2));
theta(2) = atan2(real(sqrt(1-stuff^2)),stuff);
theta2(2) = atan2(real(-sqrt(1-stuff^2)),stuff); 
IN = atan2(length(2)*sin(theta(2)),length(1)+length(2)*cos(theta(2))); 
OUT = atan2(o_wrist(2),o_wrist(1));
IN2 = atan2(length(2)*sin(theta2(2)),length(1)+length(2)*cos(theta2(2))); 
theta(1) = -IN+OUT ; %IN, IN2 negativ 
theta2(1) = -IN2+OUT;
theta(3) = omega-(theta(1)+theta(2));
theta2(3) = omega -(theta2(1)+theta2(2));
end
```

test.m

```
p1_transformed_jsp = transform([0;1], 0*sym(pi), [1,1,1])
```

file destinations:

project/test.m

project/folder1/ikin.m

project/folder2/transform.m

Comment: How does the function "myMethod" look like?

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: I have no problem with symbolic arguments and nested functions defined by m-files. I got `0` for both cases. One thing that I have noticed but may be a typo, is that in your first line which throws the error, you wrote `MyMethod` rather than `myMethod`. Is that what you have in actual code?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is lacking in details, but if I had to guess I'd say that you tried to invoke your method like this:

```
myMethod(symObject);
```

Instead of like this:

```
myObject.myMethod(symObject);   % Dot notation
% or...
myMethod(myObject, symObject);  % Function notation
```

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-invocation.html), MATLAB will look at the classes of the input arguments to a method to determine which class method to invoke. When you call your method with only a [`sym` object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html), MATLAB looks for a method named `myMethod` in the `sym` class (which it doesn't find, hence your error). To invoke the proper version of `myMethod`, you either have to add your class object `myObject` as the first input argument (i.e. [function notation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-invocation.html#bup3_xf-3)) or use [dot notation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-invocation.html#bup3_xf-3).

Comment: Problem is that I don't have a class object, I call this function in a script with several variables.

Comment: @qeia: It's hard for us to help you without seeing actual code. Could you add some sample code to the question that reproduces this error? Is your function `myMethod` even visible on the path (i.e. what does typing `which myMethod` on the command line display)?

Comment: Typing which myMethod gives me the place where it is stored. It's in the matlab path, though myMethod and another method are in different subfolders. @gnovice

Comment: @qeia: What do the paths for the two functions look like?

Comment: project/main.m ,

project/folder1/anotherMethod.m ,

project/folder2/myMethod.m @gnovice

Comment: @kassio: Are the function names and paths you've listed the *actual* names and paths, or did you change them to generic names for the sake of the question? This is turning out to be quite the conundrum.

Comment: @kassio: I have to double-check: are you *certain* your `transform` function is on the MATLAB path? Not just in the current folder (which is a part of the path, but can change), but in the actual [path file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html)? Try this: `addpath('project/folder2'); p1_transformed_jsp = transform([0;1], 0*sym(pi), [1,1,1]);`

Comment: When I write addpath('home/kassio/projects/project/folder2') nothing changes. Plus I always do "add all folders and selected subfolders to path" on my project folder. It works on your machine, doesn't it?